# How to make .tar.gz with date in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Help me please to understand. How to fit the path to the folder and archive files in the command?
I wanted to add a date to the archive as in Linux, like (date +% y-% m-% d).

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

let date = new Date();
var cmd = `'cd /root/mikrotik_weekly_backup/'+ ' '+ 'tar -zxfc router.tar.gz'+'${date}' '/root/mikrotik_weekly_backup'`;

My Output: error: Command failed: 'cd /root/mikrotik_weekly_backup/'+' '+'tar -zxfc router.tar.gz'+'Thu Apr 08 2021 16:10:42 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)' /root/mikrotik_weekly_backup
/bin/sh: 1: cd /root/mikrotik_weekly_backup/+ +tar -zxfc router.tar.gz+Thu Apr 08 2021 16:10:42 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time): not found
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the date? Include it in the filename? The string you're creating above is...odd.

Comment: I'm trying to add date to the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. Don't use `cd` in the command being run, use the `cwd` option that `exec` (and others) accept instead.
2. As far as I can make out the string you were trying to create, it would be trying to back up `/root/mikrotik_weekly_backup` while writing to a file in `/root/mikrotik_weekly_backup`, which doesn't seem ideal.
3. Trying to append to a filename using a string with spaces and no escaping won't work, because the space (in a command line) would delimit the argument; the default string from a `Date` object makes for a verbose and problematic filename in any case.
4. Don't try to build command line strings. Instead, use [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) so you pass each argument individually and don't have to worry about

Roughly:

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const date = [
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    date.getDate(),
    date.getHours(),
    date.getMinutes(),
    date.getSeconds(),
].map(x => String(x).padStart(2, "0")).join("-");
// Or just `const 
const child = spawn(
    // Command
    "tar",
    // Arguments
    ["-zxfc", `router-${date}.tar.gz`, "path/to/what/you/want/backed/up"],
    // `spawn` options
    {
        cwd: "/root/mikrotik_weekly_backup"
    }
);
child.on("close", code => {
    // ...look at `code` to see what happened...
});
```